# Kendo Datasource Model Design

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui-mvc

I am new to Kendo UI, so need your help.
Please provide your thoughts to achieve the expected result.

Here is the details:

- I am designing a web page, which is shown here:

[image]

- I have a textbox where Name should get binded on UI.
  I have a kendo Grid where the listing should get binded on UI.
- With Create/Update/Delete, I should able to get the values from UI to Controller method, so that I can work on the data.
- Please let me know how can I achieve this requirement.

(I can able to bind the data to either kendo Grid or textbox. But didn't how to bind the data to both controls using one kendo datasource. I have some more controls on UI, which are of this type only. Need to bind all the controls at once with one kendo datasource.)

(I'm using Kendo jQuery scripts. Not Kendo.MVC.dll. I mean, not Razor syntax).

Comment: please embed images directly instead of linking them

Comment: How can I edit to embed the images now.?! :(

Comment: I edited it, needs to be peer-reviewed first. you can click on the picture icon when you make/edit your post and then post a link or upload a pic directly.